# trying to implement [self.delegate.view addSubview:]

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I am trying to make a reusable class that handles iAds.

In my `.h file` I do the following:

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@protocol AdHelperDelegate;

@interface AdHelper:NSObject<ADBannerViewDelegate>

@property (strong) id<AdHelperDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ADBannerView *iAdBannerView;
...
@end

@protocol AdHelperDelegate;
@end
```

Then in my `.m file` I implement the iAd banner:

```
-(void)showBanner
{
    self.iAdBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.iAdBannerView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.iAdBannerView.frame, 0, 361);
    self.iAdBannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    self.iAdBannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    self.iAdBannerView.delegate = self;
    [self.delegate.view addSubview:self.iAdBannerView];
}
```

I of course also implement the delegate method `-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error`

I am planing to call up the `AdHelper` in a `UIViewController` in my project
with something like:

```
AdHelper *ah = [[AdHelper alloc] init];
ah.delegate = self;
[ah showBanner];
```

Problem is that the compiler is saying: `Property 'view' not found on object of type 'id<AdHelperDelegate>'`
Is there a way for me to access the delegate's view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually cast your view controller so that the compiler knows what kind of object you have:

```
[((MyViewController *)self.delegate).view addSubview:self.iAdBannerView];
```

You could also change the declaration of the view from `id<AdHelperDelegate>` to `UIViewController<AdHelperDelegate>*`, which would eliminate the need for casting in this case.

Comment: If I try `@property (strong) UIViewController*<AdHelperDelegate>delegate;`it tells me that it expects a semicolon after the `*`. If I try it without the star the compiler complains as well.

Comment: Oops, maybe that should be `UIViewController<AdHelperDelegate> *`, with the star after the protocol name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the `id` to a `UIViewController`. The compiler has no way of knowing that id has a view property.

```
[((UIViewController *)self.delegate).view addSubview:self.iAdBannerView];
```